# appcenter checks for updates but doesn't display any

Tags: appcenter

Going to the Installed page of AppCenter shows the usual "Checking for Updates; Downing a list ..." message along with a spinning wheel in the lower right corner saying the same thing, but when the latter goes away the main page is not updated: It just continues to say "Checking for Updates; Downing a list ..." indefinitely and never shows me a list of updates to install (I've been waiting half an hour). I stopped and restarted the AppCenter, and tried again, with the same result.

It's been flaky like this before, but now it seems to have stopped working completely.

Comment: I should mention that, after the wheel stops spinning, the badge at the top indicates that there are 9 updates to install; it just doesn't show them to me or give me any way to install them.